# unable to load crystal report in windows server 2012

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have created a web application .net 2008 with crystal report. I have deployed it in windows server 2012 64 bit OS. The server is installed with 3.5 and 4.0 .net frame work. The problem is, the crystal report is not displayed in the web page. It doesn't throw any error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In windows server 2012 it runs IIS 8. Previous versions of crystal report doesnt support IIS8. For running Crystal report for IIS 8 you have to install new

> crystal report**(v. 13.0.6.x)**

on your win server machine. Please check following link for downloading crystal report.

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: I did not find anything in SAP's wiki/release notes explicitly saying "download this release to support IIS 8" but I downloaded the latest version and that solved the issue. It seems older versions of the crystal runtime still work in offline (windows) applications but yes you need to download the latest runtime for crystal (in my case v13.0.13) for it to run within IIS 8.

Answer (score 0):

See below articles.
http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2012/10/16/report-appears-blank-in-browser-after-deploying-a-crystal-reportsnet-web-application

Also, make sure you are using a supported browser version.
See supported platforms for CR for VS developer version.
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21990

Comment: As to the first part of your answer: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.